# How to pretty print using System.Text.Json for unknown object

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, system.text.json, asp.net5

Using System.Text.Json i can pretty print json using serialization option.

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{ WriteIndented = true };
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(typeToSerialize, options);
```

However, I have string JSON and don't know the concrete type. Ho do I pretty-print JSON string?

My old code was using Newtonsoft and I could do it without serialize/deserialize

```cs
public static string JsonPrettify(this string json)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
    {
        return json;
    }

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
        jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no built-in API to copy from a `Utf8JsonReader` to a `Utf8JsonWriter` so parsing to `JsonDocument` and reserializing looks to be the way to go.  See [How to pretty-print (format) System.Text.JsonElement to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61598778/3744182).

Answer (score 67):

This works:

```csharp
using System.Text.Json;
public static string JsonPrettify(this string json)
{
    using var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(jDoc, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
}
```

Comment: `JsonDocument` is `IDisposable`, and must be disposed in order to return pooled memory to the memory pool for reuse.

Comment: You're right, @dbc. I added a using. Good catch.

Comment: This doesn't work. 
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'JsonDocument'.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
    private static string PrettifyJson(string jsonString)
    {
        using (JsonDocument jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString)){
            // Convert the JsonDocument back to a pretty-printed JSON string
            string prettifiedJson = 
            System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonDocument.RootElement, new 
                JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    WriteIndented = true
                });
            return prettifiedJson;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it with `Newtonsoft.Json` JToken class.
Here is the code.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static string JsonPrettify(this string json)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
    {
        return json;
    }
    return JToken.Parse(json).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
}
```